# URL Encoded Base64 Encoded File Data

Tags: c#, php, urlencode, url-encoding

I'm trying to encode an image url to Base64 in ASP.NET so that that an open source API can process my request.  The support team on the open source end of things sent me this code from their PHP system.  I'm having problem translating that into a C# equivalent.

PHP Code:

```
$data = urlencode(base64_encode(fread(fopen("/tmp/signature.jpg", "r"),      filesize("/tmp/signature.jpg"))));
```

Things I have tried so far:

```
string data = "http://url.com/image.jpg"
byte[] encbuff = HttpUtility.UrlEncodeToBytes(data);
string enc = Convert.ToBase64String(encbuff);
string urlenc = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(data);
```

Any help would be appreciated, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The PHP `fopen` and `fread` functions are opening a file and reading its bytes. You're only working with the URL. You need to download it, or open if it's a local file, first:

```
byte[] data;
using (var webClient = new WebClient())
    data = webClient.DownloadData("http://url.com/image.jpg");
string enc = Convert.ToBase64String(data);
string urlenc = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(enc);
```

Comment: MapServerPath + [File.ReadAllBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes.aspx) would be likely more inline with `fopen`/`fread`. And need to use length somewhere.

Comment: From the fact that the question stated the data would be `"http://url.com/image.jpg"`, I assumed this would be run from another computer than where the image is stored; if this is incorrect, then `ReadAllBytes` is a good way to read it. The C# code doesn't need you to specify the file length in order to do anything you're doing here; even though it comes into play in the PHP, we don't need to use it anywhere here.

Comment: +1. You right - I did not count braces... - no need for length.